# Matlab: error bars broken

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, figure, errorbar

I am trying to add error bars to a line plot, using MATLAB R2015a.

I've gotten so far that dots are plotted as error bars - not lines that go up and down from the points.

YLim is 0 to 100.
One of the standard deviations (length of error line) is 10, so it is impossible for it to be plotted as only a dot.

This lead me to think that something is bugged in my `errorbar()` function.

Copying the following code from Matlab's errorbar help:

```
x = 0:pi/10:pi;
y = sin(x);
e = std(y)*ones(size(x));

figure
errorbar(x,y,e)
```

produces an empty figure, not a sine wave with error bars as in the help file...

Any idea what might be going on?

Comment: I don't get an empty figure.  This is what I get: http://i.stack.imgur.com/4mM1F.png .  I am using MATLAB R2015a on Mac OS X 10.10.

Comment: I'm also on MATLAB R2015a, but Win10. Here is what I get: http://imgur.com/0Q4D29p


I'm going to restart my computer to see if that by any chance fixes it. BRB

Comment: I'm back, and still only get a white figure

Comment: Try just plotting the points, them use `hold on` with the `errorbar` after... something like `figure; hold on; plot(x,y); errorbar(x,y,e);`

Comment: `x = 0:pi/10:pi;
y = sin(x);
e = std(y)*ones(size(x));
figure;
plot(x,y);
hold on;
errorbar(x,y,e);`

gives the following: http://imgur.com/csJuKir

Comment: Looks like your `errorbar` function is indeed broken.  Raise a MathWorks support ticket.

Comment: Will do, thanks for your help

Comment: My pleasure.  Sorry I couldn't help you resolve it!

Comment: It still is some progress - now I know why I couldn't get it to work. Now I'm just hoping that the support people will reply quickly.

Or I will have to learn Python scripting to do my plot

Comment: @Mierzen - Tested this on MATLAB 2015b on Win10. No such problem here. Could you please save your figure as a `.fig` file and upload it somewhere so we could take a look? I suspect that the axes' `children` are there but are not visible for some reason.

Comment: @Dev-iL Here is the fig file https://dl.dropbox.com/s/iotgzvevs87ihzd/stupid_error_bars.fig?dl=1

Comment: @Mierzen Well.... Everything is visible when I load it in my MATLAB, and also on a computer running 2015a on Win7 - still can see it. Could you please update the question with the output of `get(gca,'Children')` if you run this code right after plotting?

Comment: You don't have a variable called `errorbar`, do you? If you do, you can get rid of it by issuing `clear errorbar`.

Comment: I don't have a variable named that. In fact fact, I even spammed 'clear all' before trying

Comment: @Mierzen - Try setting breakpoints inside `errorbar` and seeing where something strange happens.

Comment: @Dev-iL TBH, I don't know if something strange is happening there. Well, I guess something strange **is**, otherwise it would be working...

But anyway, breakpoints in `errorbar.m` show that it executes line 35 (`h = errorbarHGUsingMATLABClasses(cax, args{:});`), then goes to L122 (`if nargout>0, hh = h; end`), that's it.

Comment: What version of MATLAB are you using? Loading the `.fig` in R2014a shows the correct plot too.

Comment: @IKavanagh I am using MATLAB R2015a on Windows 10. I will update my quetsion to reflect that